# Makefile variable autocompletion in bash

Tags: bash, variables, autocomplete, makefile

Let's say my `Makefile` is something like:

```
DIR :=#

foobar:

   ls ${DIR}
```

When i type

```
mak[tab] f[tab]
```

it gives correctly

```
make foobar
```

But

```
make foobar D[tab]
```

doesn't do the magic

```
make foobar DIR=
```

So my question is: is there a way to autocomplete Makefile variables too (aside targets) in bash?

Comment: To do this you would need to modify the make bash completion function which extracts the target names to also extract variable names. It should be possible to do that though I cannot say how much work it would be.

Comment: I am almost certain that bash is completing "foobar" not because "foobar" is a target in the makefile, but because you have a file named `foobar`.

Comment: @Beta thanks for feedback! no, for testing purposes i made 2 subdirs (named "asd" and "qwe") in the Makefile dir. BTW i'm using Debian testing, make 4.0 and bash 4.3.24

Comment: @Beta ... and i don't have further files (especially named "foobar") in my dir (but Makefile)

Answer (score 3):

This answer is far from complete. To grep all variables in a Makefile we use `make -p` to print the *Makefile database*:

```
# GNU Make 3.81
# Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
# This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
# There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
# PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

# This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

# Make data base, printed on Mon Oct 13 13:36:12 2014

# Variables

# automatic
<D = $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $<))
# automatic
?F = $(notdir $?)
# environment
DESKTOP_SESSION = kde-plasma
# ...
# makefile (from `Makefile', line 1)
DIR :=
```

We are looking for lines starting with `# makefile (from 'Makefile', line xy)` and extract the name of the following variable:

```
$ make -p | sed -n '/# makefile (from/ {n; p;}'
MAKEFILE_LIST :=  Makefile
DIR :=
```

In the next step we remove everything but the variable name (everything after `:=`):

```
$ make -p Makefile | sed -n '/# makefile (from/ {n; s/^\([^.#:= ]\+\) *:\?=.*$/\1/p;}'
MAKEFILE_LIST
DIR
```

The following lines demonstrate how it could be done:

```
_make_variables()
{
  # get current completion
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  # get list of possible makefile variables
  local var=$(make -p Makefile | sed -n '/# makefile (from/ {n; s/^\([^.#:= ]\+\) *:\?=.*$/\1=/p;}')
  # don't add a space after completion
  compopt -o nospace

  # find possible matches
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${var}" -- ${cur}) )
}

# use _make_variables to complete make arguments
complete -F _make_variables make
```

Now `make D[tab]` results in `make DIR=`.

Sadly you will loose all the file and target completion with this approach. Also it would be useful to remove some more variables (e.g. `MAKEFILE_LIST`) from the completion output.

Maybe it is worth to fill a wish/bug report against the [bash-completion project](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) to add this feature.

Comment: thanks, +1. Filled a wishlist item at bash-completion project.